# Mockito testing a function that throws log error

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

I am new to writing test cases.
I need to test a part of a function that does not return anything.
It should be able to validate containsHello  is true
or
check if a log error is obtained or not

```
public void Myfunction(x){
Boolean containsHello;

if (x != null) {

    if ((x.contains(“hello"))
      {
        containsHello = true;
        
        if (AppConfig.isWord()
                && (Secondclass.isSentence() && containsHello)) {
            log.error("");
        }
    }
}

More code
}
```

Secondclass is a final class defined outside of the current .java file
AppConfig is also a class that exists outside the java file being tested.

How to run a test for the above code using Mockito. I tried the below code But does not work:

```
@Test
public void TestingmyFunction() throws Exception {

String x=“hello"
Mockito.when(Secondclass.isSentence()).thenReturn(true);

Mockito.when(AppConfig.isWord()).thenReturn(true);


Myfunction(x);
}
```

But I am not able to access the AppConfig.isWord() or Secondclass.isSentence()

Tried with powerMockito which throws this error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name com.amazon.alfred.cli.action.DeployBundleTests. Reason: javassist.bytecode.InterfaceMethodrefInfo cannot be cast to javassist.bytecode.MethodrefInfo

```
@Test
public void TestingmyFunction() throws Exception {

String x=“hello"

PowerMockito.mockStatic(Secondclass.class)
PowerMockito.when(Secondclass.isSentence()).thenReturn(true);
PowerMockito.mockStatic(AppConfig.class);
PowerMockito.when(AppConfig.isWord()).thenReturn(true);


Myfunction(x);
}
```

Comment: What type is `log`?

Comment: it is slf4j logger factory

Comment: `AppConfig.isWord()` and `Secondclass.isSentence()` appears to be static methods, you can not mock static methods using mockito.  Use Powermockito instead. And i will suggest to refactor the method `Myfunction` to return boolean as it is testing contains "hello".

Comment: Although the answer to this question doesnt use Mockito, it should verify a log entry was written, it might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62623403/how-to-verify-with-unit-test-that-error-stack-is-printed-in-the-log-file/62635351#62635351

Comment: Then you should look at slf4j-test.